# How to remove line during compilation?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm currently working on a typescript file that I use on a webpage.
I'm importing typed.js for the type definitions because adding `@types/typed.js` with yarn doesn't do anything because there's no types, which seems stupid imo.

So right now I'm importing typed.js in my ts file, but I don't want it to actually be imported, and I just want the type defs.

```
import Typed from 'typed.js';
```

What can I do to make this not be included in the compiled file?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything. TypeScript removes type-only imports on its own. Have you looked at the compiled file?

Comment: Yes and it imports typed.js which I don't want it to do, and if I leave it in the file, browsers will complain saying "require is not a function" and I don't want to use webpack or browserify.